# How to get multiple logins from a single textfile working into console?

Tags: c#

Making a console where user enters his username and password from a textfile. So far I've gotten it to work but with only one user. Here is my current code for reading one user. How do I get it to work with multiple users?

edit: thought I preface this with saying I'm just learning C# so this is all completely new to me

```
private static void LoginMenu()
{
    string username, password, username1, password1 = string.Empty;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 7);
    Console.Write("Username: ");
    username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 8);
    Console.Write("Password: ");
    password = Console.ReadLine();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(textFile, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        username1 = sr.ReadLine();
        password1 = sr.ReadLine();
        sr.Close();
    }

    if (username == username1 && password == password1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login Successful! Press any key to continue...");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(57, 13);
        Console.Clear();
        GoToMainMenu();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username or password is incorrect. Try again");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
        LoginMenu();
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

This is my text file for only one user

```
admin
123
```

I want to get it working with multiple users with text file like this: (username and password separated with commas)

```
admin,123
test,321
guest,abc
user,1234
```

Comment: Well, you've changed the format of the text file to accommodate multiple users.  What corresponding changes have you made to the _code_ to accommodate multiple users?

Comment: I think I see a flaw in your security system.

Comment: Look up CSV filer readers. Then look up `Dictionary<string, string>`. And. As @LarsTech points out, you have a glaring security issue - don't put this into production

Comment: The real challenge is to read the user's password from a post-it note on the monitor. I'd look at hijacking the laptop camera and reading reflections off the user's eyeglasses. Honeslty, that wouldn't be a much worse idea than storing everybody's passwords in cleartext on the disk.

Comment: im completely new to C# and this is like homework for me so don't think of it as a legitimate system lol.

Comment: Don't clean stoves with gasoline and don't store passwords in cleartext. Ever. For any reason. Not to learn how to use your tools, not as a shortcut, not if you're a beginner or if you'll get around to doing it right later, not as a learning exercise or as a workaround, not if you're out of oven cleaner and there's a jerry can right in the kitchen. Learn to do it right or don't do it at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Storing credentials in a plain text file is a bad idea**

Hoping its just an experiment or playing with some code kind of thing.

I assume you're trying to login a user if it matches any line in the file.  Here is a quick and dirty code, it's not compiler checked, but gets you the idea on how to do it.

```cs
private static void LoginMenu()
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 7);
    Console.Write("Username: ");
    username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 8);
    Console.Write("Password: ");
    password = Console.ReadLine();

    bool loginSuccessful = false;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(textFile, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        string line;
        // Read one line at a time from file until end of file.
        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)  
        {
            // split the line by comma.
            var creds = line.Split(',');

            // if the values match, set login to true and exit the while loop.  
            if (username == creds[0] && password == creds[1])
            {
                loginSuccessful = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
    }

    if(loginSuccessful)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login Successful! Press any key to continue...");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(57, 13);
        Console.Clear();
        GoToMainMenu();
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Username or password is incorrect. Try again");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
        LoginMenu();
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Got some code with line.Split that looked similar to this. Thanks for this. I'm understanding the concept through a video and seeing this helped made sense for me.